# powerpc compiler on windows gives "c++ compiler not installed on this system error"

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, powerpc

I am trying to use msys powerpc-eabispe-gcc compiler on windows to compile a simple helloworld.cpp program, inorder to generate an elf for powerpc architecture, but I am getting "c++ compiler not installed on this system" error. The bin folder of powerpc-eabispe contains all the exe's, I dont understand why then I get this error??

I used MinGW command prompt to run this command: powerpc-eabispe-gcc.exe -o hello hello.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the *toolchain* for the architecture you are targeting.
Search for "cctools" / "binutils" / "crosstools" or "ppc cross-compile environment".

You can also take a look at:

- [Building and Testing gcc/glibc cross toolchains](http://www.kegel.com/crosstool/) (This will probably work)
- [Host/Target specific installation notes for GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html#powerpc-x-x) (search powerpc in the page)

However, I would encourage you to try this on a linux or on a mac computer. There are far more resources & docs available on the web for cross-compilation on these platforms.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, I would love to work on linux, but my project is narrowed to windows environment!